# C# - How to open a specific panel and hide specific panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a new member on С# and I have a little problem, let me explain,
I have a list of Buttons and i need to open a specific `panel`, when I click on a button and hide a specific `panel` because I'm using some panels for design.

When I put this function it hides all other panels.
Please help!

```
private void HidePanels()
{
    foreach (var control in Controls)
        if (control is Panel)
           ((Panel)control).Visible = false;
}
```

[image: picture for design just to take the idea]

Comment: How do you decide which panel to open or hide?

Comment: panelx.visible=true
and i call the function to hide all

Comment: Do you want to show/hide all panels except `panelx`?

Comment: Please show the button-click code. Also you could explain how the screenshot is related to your problem (that the buttons are actually those on the left-hand side)

Comment: ...just call `HidePanels()` and then **afterwards** change the visibility of the one you want visible to true?

Comment: i got you i test !

Comment: i tried not work , i called 3 panel.visible = true;
the 2panel design still works and panel 3 not visible

Comment: As your code is written, the Panels **must be directly contained by the Form itself**.  Is this the case?